# Converting Matrix Definition to Zero-Indexed Notation - Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to construct a numpy array (a 2-dimensional numpy array - i.e. a matrix) from a paper that uses a non-standard indexing to construct the matrix. I.e. the top left element is q<sub>1,2</sub>. instead of q<sub>0,0</sub>.

Define the `n` x `(n-2)` matrix **Q** by its elements q<sub>i,j</sub> for `i = i,...,n` and `j = 2, ... , n-1` given by 
q<sub>j-1,j</sub>=h<sup>-1</sup><sub>j-1</sub>, q<sub>j,j</sub> = h<sup>-1</sup><sub>j-1</sub> - h<sup>-1</sup><sub>j</sub> and q<sub>j+1,j</sub>=h<sup>j</sup><sub>j-1</sub>. (I have posted this in Latex form here: http://www.texpaste.com/n/8vwds4fx)

I have tried to implement in python like this:

```
# n = u_s.size
# n = 299 for this example
n = 299
Q = np.zeros((n,n-2))

for i in range(0,n+1):
    for j in range(2,n):
        Q[j-1,j] = 1.0/h[j-1]
        Q[j,j] = -1.0/h[j-1] - 1.0/h[j]
        Q[j+1,j] = 1.0/h[j]
```

But I always get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-c07a3b1c81bb> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(1,n+1):
      2     for j in range(2,n-1):
----> 3         Q[j-1,j] = 1.0/h[j-1]
      4         Q[j,j] = -1.0/h[j-1] - 1.0/h[j]
      5         Q[j+1,j] = 1.0/h[j]

IndexError: index 297 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 297
```

I initially thought I could decrement both `i` and `j` in my `for` loop to keep edge cases safe, as a quick way to move to zero-indexed notation, but this hasn't worked. I also tried incrementing and modifying the `range()`.

Is there a way to convert this definition to one that python can handle? Is this a common issue?

Comment: Why are you are looping on `i` but never using it in the loop?

Comment: You're correct. Because I initialized elements with `np.zeros()`, looping over `i` is not necessary. It would only be necessary if each element needed to be defined as zero, or in a strict definition.

Comment: Looks like you are setting 3 diagonals.  I.e. for each column `j` set 3 row values.  `numpy` arrays don't really have a `top left`, but it is easy to `flip` after construction.  Is the one occurrence of `h^j` correct?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the problem to make the assignment pattern obvious:

```
In [228]: h=np.arange(10,15)
In [229]: Q=np.zeros((5,5),int)
In [230]: for j in range(1,5):
     ...:     Q[j-1:j+2,j] = h[j-1:j+2]

In [231]: Q
Out[231]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12, 12, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 13, 13, 13],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 14, 14]])
```

Assignment to the partial first and last columns may need tweaking.  Here's the equivalent built from diagonals:

```
In [232]: np.diag(h,0)+np.diag(h[:-1],1)+np.diag(h[1:],-1)
Out[232]: 
array([[10, 10,  0,  0,  0],
       [11, 11, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12, 12, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 13, 13, 13],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 14, 14]])
```

With the `h[j-1]`, `h[j]` indexing this diagonal assignment probably needs tweaking, but it should be a useful starting point.

---

Selecting `h` values more like what you use (skipping the `1/h` for now):

```
In [238]: Q=np.zeros((5,5),int)
In [239]: for j in range(1,4):
     ...:     Q[j-1:j+2,j] =[h[j-1],h[j-1]+h[j], h[j]]
     ...:     
In [240]: Q
Out[240]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 21, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11, 23, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12, 25,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 13,  0]])
```

I'm skipping the two partial end columns for now.  The first slicing approach allowed me to be a bit sloppy, since it's ok to slice 'off the end'.  The end columns, if set, will require their own expressions.

```
In [241]: j=0; Q[j:j+2,j] =[h[j], h[j]]  
In [242]: j=4; Q[j-1:j+1,j] =[h[j-1],h[j-1]+h[j]] 
In [243]: Q
Out[243]: 
array([[10, 10,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 21, 11,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 11, 23, 12,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12, 25, 13],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 13, 27]])
```

The relevant diagonal pieces are still evident:

```
In [244]: h[1:]+h[:-1]
Out[244]: array([21, 23, 25, 27])
```

Answer (score 0):

The equation doesn't contain any value for i.  It is referring only to j.  The Q should be a matrix of dimension n+2 x n+2.  For j = 1, it refers to Q[0,1], Q[1,1] and Q[2,1].  for j =n, it refers to Q[n-1,n], Q[n,n] and Q[n+1,n].  So, Q should have indices from 0 to n+1 which n+2

I don't think, you require the i loop.  You can achieve your results only with j loop from 1 to n, but Q should be from 0 to n+1

Comment: **Q** is a matrix defined to be `n` x `n-2` elements.

Comment: Which I believe in `range()` will be from `range(0,n-1)` and `range(0,n-3)`